# Spectrum of direct sum of bounded operators

Tags: operator-algebras, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I recently learned something about spectrum in functional analysis and saw some examples. However I struggling with this when trying to understand how it can be used for the following example regarding Hilbert spaces. I will write the example below.

Let $H_1,H_2$ be Hilbert spaces, then the direct sum $H_1\oplus H_2$ is given by the following
$$\langle (x_1,y_1)|(x_2,y_2)\rangle:=\langle x_1|x_2 \rangle_{H_1}+\langle y_1|y_2 \rangle_{H_2}.$$
Let $T_1\oplus T_2$ be given where $T_1\in B(H_1)$ and $T_2\in B(H_2)$. How can one find the spectrum of $T_1\oplus T_2$?

I have the definition of the spectrum as follows:

**Definition:** Let $A\in \mathscr{A}$, where $\mathscr{A}$ is a unital Banach algebra. The spectrum of $A$ denoted $\sigma(A)$ is $\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}:A-\lambda I \text{ is not invertible in } \mathscr{A}\}$. Of course we have $I$ as our unit.

---

Notice that I now know that $\sigma(T_1\oplus T_2)=\sigma(T_1)\cup \sigma(T_2)$ so I have to compute each $\sigma(T_1)$ and $\sigma(T_2)$. I have to compute $\det(\lambda I_1-T_1)$ and $\det(\lambda I_2-T_2)$ however what matrices should I use?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Operators on infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces do not have determinants, in general. The task of determining the spectrum of a given operator in infinite-dimensions is typically very difficult (unless for very specific examples or example classes). That's the whole point of many results and methods in spectral theory: typically one can't compute the spectrum, so one needs techniques which still allow to obtain non-trivial information about it.

Comment: Hi, yes that was a mistake. I mean union which is now corrected.
Regarding my post. I want to compute the spectrum of $T_1\oplus T_2$.

Comment: Yes sure, you wrote this in the question. But you also wrote that you already know how to compute the spectrum of $T_1 \oplus T_2$ from the spectra of $T_1$ and $T_2$ (namely, it's the union). That's essentially all that one can say about $\sigma(T_1 \oplus T_2)$, so what more would you like to know?

Comment: Yea I can compute the spectrum by taking the union of each spectra, but what matrices should I use? I mean. We have
$T_1 \oplus T_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
T_1 & 0 \\
0 & T_2
\end{pmatrix}$
but then what? How would one compute $\sigma(T_1)$ and $\sigma(T_2)$? I cannot see through this

Comment: Sorry, we seem to be talking past each other. What makes you think that this has something to do with matrices? You merely said that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are bounded linear operators on $H_1$ and $H_2$, respectively. Without knowing more about $T_1$ and $T_2$ one obviously can't compute their spectrum, because the spectrum of a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space can be every compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I believe that my problem is a finite-dimensional space and therefore one would be able to compute the spectrum. I know that when discussing infinite-dimensional spaces one would have a hard time to compute this. And thats why I mention matrices. I can use the definition of spectra and compute the determinant of $\lambda I_1-T_1$. Sorry if I am not clear.

Comment: So $H_1$ and $H_2$ are finite-dimensional?

Comment: Yeah because if it infinite then I cannot see how one would be able to compute as you already mentioned before. I should have written that before.

Comment: Well, even in finite dimensions you do, of course, need to know how $T_1$ acts in order to compute its spectrum. If you are asking for an explicit algorithm, you can for instance do the following (although that's not always the most straightforward thing to do): if $B = (b_1, \dots, b_n)$ is a basis of $H_1$ and $M_1 \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ is the respresentation matrix of $T_1$ with respect to the basis $B$, then $\sigma(M_1) = \sigma(T_1)$, so it suffices to compute $\sigma(M_1)$ by standard methods from linear algebra.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: Indeed, that would have been my next comment, too.

Comment: @TheCalcLover1231: No, this doesn't seem directly related to your question. But standard functional analysis/spectral theory textbooks should help here (I would normally refer you to my own functional analysis lecture notes, except that this is an exercise there).

Comment: Fair I though this site was another math forum but I can see that this is for research questions. Thank you for your time!

Christian would you mind to share your notes?

Comment: @TheCalcLover1231: General advice when talking mathematics on the internet: if somebody talks about "referring you to their lecture notes" without additional information, it's pretty save to assume that you'll find the lecture notes on their webpage. ;-)

Comment: Yea I actually found his webpage so ignore my comment. hehe :-)

Comment: @TheCalcLover1231: They are here, the relevant statement is Proposition 10.9: https://math.ou.edu/~cremling/teaching/lecturenotes/fa-new/ln10.pdf